# I have added two grid items but i could see only one grid appearing

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, xcode14

```
let Columns: [GridItem] = [
    GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: nil, alignment: nil),
    GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: nil, alignment: nil),

]
var body: some View {

    LazyVGrid(columns: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*//*@PLACEHOLDER=Columns@*/[GridItem(.fixed(200))]/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
        ScrollView{
            ForEach(0..<20) { index in
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height:150)
                                }
       
        }

    }
}
```

i expected two rectangle but i could see only one appearing on the screen

Comment: Why not pass the property `Columns` you have created to `LazyVGrid(columns:)` instead of creating a new array with only one element?

Answer (score 0):

try this, having the `ScrollView` before the `LazyVGrid`:

```
    struct LazyView: View {
    
    let Columns: [GridItem] = [
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: nil, alignment: nil),
        GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: nil, alignment: nil)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {  // <--- here
            LazyVGrid(columns: Columns) {
                ForEach(0..<20) { index in
                    Rectangle().foregroundColor(Color.red).frame(height:150)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did my answer worked for you?